# Kafka Log4j Configuration

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am have following warning on start kafka:

> No appenders could be found for logger (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkConnection

Also I tried to change level in config/log4j.properties to DEBUG, but in logs/server.log I still see INFO level messages without any debug output. Looks like kafka don't take log4j properties from config/log4.properties.

Maybe someone have idea what could be wrong?

Thanks in advance.

This issue about configuration logging for kafka, not about my web application

Comment: You'll see this warning if log4j can't find a file "log4j.properties" or "log4j.xml" anywhere.

Comment: I don't startup my application. I am starting Kafka